# Docker - SpringConfig - Connection refused to ConfigServer

Tags: docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to deploy a ConfigServrService and a Client with a remote repository using DockerCompose.

The docker-compose.yml is like:

```
version: '2'

services:

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"

  config-server:
    image: config-server
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=desa"
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq

  user-service-config:
    image: user-service-config
    environment:
      - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=desa"
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    links:
      - config-server
      - rabbitmq
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
      - config-server
```

At the moment that they are deploying, the client console shows:

> c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server
>   at: http://localhost:8888

(Instead of http://config-server:8888)

And after that, the console shows:

> Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for
>   "http://localhost:8888/user-server-config/desa": Connection refused;
>   nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

The service is trying to connet to http://localhost:8888/user-server-config/desa instead of http://config-server:8888.

The application.yml file of the client is:

```
server:
  port: 8090
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: 172.17.0.1
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

  application:
    name: user-server-config
  cloud:
    enabled: true
    config:
      uri: http://config-server:8888
      failFast: true
      retry:
        maxAttempts: 20

management:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

I do not know why the uri contains **http://localhost:8888** with **/user-server-config/desa** at the end. Instead of **http://server-config:8888** as is indicated in the application.yml

Comment: those values should be in `bootstrap.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005558/docker-springconfig-connection-refused-to-configserver/43009889#comment73105955_43005558), and as the [official documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html) suggests, create a `bootstrap.yml` file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    enabled: true
    config:
      uri: http://config-server:8888
      failFast: true
      retry:
        maxAttempts: 20
```

and remove the above included properties from `application.yml`.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! @Hasan Can Saral and @spencergibb!