# docker ports not available

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a spring-config-sever project that I am trying to run via Docker.  I can run it from the command line and my other services and browser successfully connect via:

> http://localhost:8980/aservice/dev

However, if I run it via Docker, the call fails.

My config-server has a Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/my-config-server-0.1.0.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} my-config-server-0.1.0.jar
EXPOSE 8980
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/my-config-server-0.1.0.jar"]
```

I build via:

> docker build -t my-config-server .

I am running it via:

> docker run my-config-server -p 8980:8980

And then I confirm it is running via

> docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1cecafdf99fe        my-config-server   "java -Djava.securit…"   14 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds       8980/tcp            suspicious_brahmagupta
```

When I run it via Docker, the browse fails with a "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and my calling services fails with:

> Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for
>   "http://localhost:8980/aservice/dev": Connection refused (Connection
>   refused);

Comment: Looks like host port is not mapped. Try `docker run -p 8980:8980 my-config-server`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker - SpringConfig - Connection refused to ConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005558/docker-springconfig-connection-refused-to-configserver)

Comment: I think this is a good start - by changing my command per Imran, I am able to run the config server in Docker, and view the properties in a browser.  However, other Dockerized services are still getting the  `c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8980/aservice/dev": Connection refused `.  I am launching those services via : `docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -p 3009:8980 -t aservice
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding full answer based on comments.

First, you have to specify `-p` before image name.
`docker run -p 8980:8980 my-config-server`.

Second, just configuring `localhost` with host port won't make your my-service container to talk to other container. `locahost` in container is within itself(not host). You will need to use appropriate [docker networking model](https://docs.docker.com/network/) so both containers can talk to each other.

If you are on Linux, the default is `Bridge` so you can configure my-config-server container ip `docker inspect {containerIp-of-config-server}` as your config server endpoint.

Example if your my-config-server ip is 172.17.0.2 then endpoint is - http://172.17.0.2:8980/

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://172.17.0.2:8980
```

Just follow the docker documentation for little bit more understanding on how networking works.
https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/

If you want to spin up both containers using docker-compose, then you can link both containers using service name. Just follow [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer.  I found my local ip via "ifconfig" on my Mac.  I then passed it in via: `docker run -e "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev" -e "SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URL=HTTP://10.0.0.143:8980" -p 3009:8980 -t my-config-server`

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine that the application only listens on localhost, ie 127.0.0.1.

You might want to try setting the property `server.address` to `0.0.0.0`. 
Then port 8980 should also be available externally.