# Docker Compose - Service name not working as environment variable

Tags: docker-compose, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to use docker-compose to setup a Spring Cloud project.

I'm using spring cloud configuration so I have a Configuration Server and some services.

For now, I have 3 services in my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root' # TODO: Change this
            MYSQL_USER: 'user'
            MYSQL_PASS: 'password'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        volumes:
            - "db:/opt/mysql/docker:rw"
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"

    config:
        image: config-server
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/ec_settings?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC                
        ports:
            - "8100:8100"

    gateway:
        image: gateway
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - config
        environment:
            - CONFIG_URI=http://config:8100
        ports:
            - '8081:8080'

volumes:
    db: {}
```

In gateway microservice, in bootstrap.yml, i have this setting

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: ${CONFIG_URI}
```

When i put up the docker composer i see that gateway service is trying to fetch configuration from `http://config:8100`

```
 Fetching config from server at : http://config:8100
```

So, the variable passes to Spring Boot but docker-compose does not replace the service name with its actual link.
The very strange thing is that *SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL* environment variable gets translated correctly in config service to connect to db service.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it thanks to this link [Docker - SpringConfig - Connection refused to ConfigServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005558/docker-springconfig-connection-refused-to-configserver)

The problem was the service was trying to fetch the config url too early.
Solution is to put in bootstrap.yml this settings

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      retry:
        max-attempts: 20
```